Error 504 when nginx proxypass to Flask app, but it's fine when docker port mapping
Question：
First of all, I get a 504 error in my AWS EC2 instance establishing several containers.
I use nginx container to proxypass a 「POST」 request to my Flask backend container. After nginx send 504 to client, my Flask backend container feedbacks. However, when I use docker mapping, it can login correctly.
Code below：
docker compose config:
services:
    nginx:
      container_name: nginx-https
      image: nginx:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
      links:
       - web
       - twittor
       - sketch
      volumes:
       - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
       - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:rw
       - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
    sketch:
      ports:
       - "8002:8002"
      container_name: sharing_sketch_20240711
      environment:
       - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      image: pss_websocket

docker ps:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                                                      NAMES
fc69badf4f09   pss_websocket   "./run_server.sh"        47 hours ago   Up 46 hours   0.0.0.0:8002->8002/tcp, :::8002->8002/tcp                                  sharing_sketch_20240711
2e8770807b4b   nginx:latest    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 days ago     Up 3 days     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   nginx-https

nginx config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.195.89.113;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://sharing_sketch_20240711:8002;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        # WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # Set timeouts
        proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        proxy_send_timeout 120s;
        proxy_cache off;
    }
}

Flask
backend
run_server.sh
#!/bin/sh

gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 --threads 5 -b 0.0.0.0:8002 PSS.wsgi:application --access-logfile ./access.log --error-logfile ./error.log

wsgi.py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
from PSS import create_app

application = create_app()

route.py
def index():
    # if current_user.is_authenticated:
    #     return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form=Loginform(meta={'csrf': False})
    print("index")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("submit")
        u=User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        print("query")
        if u is None or not u.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash("Invalid username or password")
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        session.clear()
        login_user(u,remember=form.remember_me.data)
        session['roomname']=form.roomname.data
        session['username']=form.username.data
        return redirect(url_for('room'))
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)

The website demo：
You can log in with account.[IP：8002->username：123;pw：123;room：123]
http://52.195.89.113:8002/ [if no port it can't login.]
Debug attempt：
1.Nginx can't connect to backend:
However, I can curl from nginx container inside(by using docker exec) to backend container.[curl http://sharing_sketch_20240711:8002;and get the index.html code]
2.Backend server is so busy：
However,when I use docker port mapping, login is fine.
3.Backend doesn't receive the message from nginx container:
I try to use tcpdump,and get the error 504 in containers' web. I think that nginx container sends to backend correctly, however backend doesn't react to nginx, until error 504.
tcpdump logs(sudo tcpdump -i br-2c93da463f14)
08:24:51.123625 IP ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.39846 > ip-172-25-0-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.8002: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 711757314 ecr 296518398], length 0

08:24:51.123675 IP ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.39846 > ip-172-25-0-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.8002: Flags [P.], seq 1:668, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 711757314 ecr 296518398], length 667
08:26:01.810397 IP ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.http > 223-137-21-214.emome-ip.hinet.net.18981: Flags [.], ack 586, win 501, options [nop,nop,sack 1 {585:586}], length 0
08:26:51.199534 IP ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.39846 > ip-172-25-0-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.8002: Flags [F.], seq 668, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 711877390 ecr 296518398], length 0
08:26:51.201095 IP ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.http > 223-137-21-214.emome-ip.hinet.net.18981: Flags [P.], seq 1:330, ack 586, win 501, length 329: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out
08:26:51.241080 IP ip-172-25-0-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.8002 > ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.39846: Flags [.], ack 669, win 504, options [nop,nop,TS val 296638516 ecr 711877390], length 0
08:26:51.313524 IP 223-137-21-214.emome-ip.hinet.net.18981 > ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.http: Flags [.], ack 330, win 511, length 0
08:26:51.364082 IP ip-172-25-0-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.8002 > ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.39846: Flags [P.], seq 1:431, ack 669, win 504, options [nop,nop,TS val 296638639 ecr 711877390], length 430
08:26:51.364106 IP ip-172-25-0-5.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.39846 > ip-172-25-0-3.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal.8002: Flags [R], seq 2748267786, win 0, length 0

So, how can I check which part causes Error 504, and revise the code?

First thing I would try is changing 52.195.89.113 with sketch in nginx config.

Thanks for reply!However, 「location / {proxy_pass http://52.195.89.113:8002;...」is not use.By tcpdump records, nginx transfer 504 to client, then nginx ack to backend, then backend give a feedbacks(Flags [P.], seq 1:430, ..., length 429) to nginx.

Hey! I change my run_server.sh to 「#!/bin/sh
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8002 --log-level info --workers 4 PSS.wsgi:application」, and server can login correctly. However, I have to use WebSocket server using SocketIO in /room page.How can I do?Thanks!.

Hello to anyone facing the same issue.
After several attempts, I modified the Nginx configuration as follows, and it worked.
server {
    listen 80;
    # using new aws EC2 instance IP 
    server_name 57.180.251.162;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        proxy_send_timeout 120s;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass http://sharing_sketch_20240711:8002;
    }
    location /room {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
        proxy_send_timeout 120s;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_pass http://sharing_sketch_20240711:8002;
    }
    location /socket.io {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://sharing_sketch_20240711:8002/socket.io;
    }
}

It's necessary to specify which endpoints should be upgraded by the Nginx proxy pass to avoid error.
